# "Error: expected <" when reading .xlsx and .xls files into R with readxl package

Tags: r, excel, readxl

I am reading a batch of excel files into r using the `readxl` package and a `for` loop. Here is my simplified code:

```
filelist = list.files(input.dir) #get list of excel files

for (i in seq_along(filelist)){
  read_excel(filelist[i], col_names=F)
}
```

I am able to read some files without issue. Others are read, but the result is a 0x0 tibble. Other files stop the loop and force the error message:
 `Error: expected <`

I can bypass the issue by opening a problem file, making any minor edit, and saving. However, it is not feasible to do this for every file - I have over 1,000 in total. You can find a subset of my excel files [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FsFSm346GSfP9pagWqsk4mus6hooHfie?usp=sharing). For your reference, "AMEX1-61-2020-PH.xlsx" is one of the problem files that returns the error message. I am using `readxl` version 1.3.1 and r version 4.1.1. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Bryant! Did you try to use another package to read the data? (`openxlsx::read.xlsx` maybe?) If so: Do you receive a similar error?

Comment: Using `openxlsx::read.xlsx` on a problem file produces the following error: `Error in read.xlsx.default(filelist[12]) : Workbook has no worksheets
In addition: Warning message:
In gregexpr("(?<=<sheets>).*(?=</sheets>)", workbook, perl = TRUE) :
  PCRE error
 'UTF-8 error: illegal byte (0xfe or 0xff)'
 for element 1`   However, I would prefer to use `read_excel` (or something similar) because it does not require specification for whether the file is .xls or xlsx.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure every file in the directory is an Excel file?  Print out the file list to verify.

Comment: @Dave2e All files are either .xls or .xlsx and can be opened in excel (Version 2110, 64-bit, on Windows 10 Pro) without issue. The problems in R disappear after I have opened the file in excel.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility the file(s) are corrupt (ie incorrect file format per extension, etc) and thus causing the problem with R opening it.

Here is a possible solution of writing an Excel macro to opens, re-saves and closes each file in the directory as defined by the "strDirectory" variable below.

Once this macro processes all of the files in the directory then the files should work in R.

```
Sub ResaveFiles()

    Dim varDirectory As Variant
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strDirectory As String

    strDirectory = "/Users/stacktest/Downloads/"
    i = 1
    flag = True
    varDirectory = Dir(strDirectory & "*.xls*", vbNormal)

    While flag = True
        If varDirectory = "" Then
            flag = False
        Else
           Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(varDirectory)
           Cells(1, 1) = Cells(1, 1)
           ActiveWorkbook.Save
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
            varDirectory = Dir
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: @Byrant, did this solution work for you?